# How to delete a line in a csv file after processing it with a Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, wp-cli

I use a Linux bash script to create posts on my WordPress website with wp-cli.
this is the example of the script that I use:

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS="|" read -r rec_column1 rec_column2 rec_column3 rec_column4
do
cd /posts/ &&
wp post create \
    --post_type=post \
    --post_title="$rec_column1" \
    --post_status=publish \
    --post_category=2 \
    --url=http://127.0.0.1/ \
    --meta_input="{\"word\":\"$rec_column2\"}" \
    --tags_input="$rec_column3" \
    --post_content="$rec_column4"
done < <(tail -n +2 ./files/$1) > ./logs/$1.log
```

and this is an example of the csv file that I that the data from:

```
title|word|tags|content
Lorem|ipsum|dolor|sit
amet|consectetur|adipiscing|elit
Maecenas|sed|condimentum|est
in|fermentum|justo|Aenean
```

The issue that I'm facing is that if the post creation gets interrupted for some reason, I would than have to take a look at the log file to see what was the post id of the last post created, afterwards I go to the WordPress site, see the that last post, find the line in the csv file, delete all the line above that line and start over.

I would like to improve that process so, after the post is created, the line from which that post was created in the CSV file is deleted. so next time that the post creation process gets interrupted, I will be able to continue it from the place it was stopped in.

for example if the process was stopped after the first line the new csv file will look like:

```
title|word|tags|content
amet|consectetur|adipiscing|elit
Maecenas|sed|condimentum|est
in|fermentum|justo|Aenean
```

I'll appreciate any suggestions or code modification on how to make this work like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop, store current line number in a variable `$LINE_NUMBER`.

Create a function `delete_lines()` which deletes processed lines from the input file:

```
delete_lines() {
  sed -i "1,${LINE_NUMBER}d" ./files/$FILE_NAME
  exit
}
```

Finally, set up a trap which calls this function on error, exit or script interruption:

```
trap delete_lines EXIT ERR INT TERM
```

Whole solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

LINE_NUMBER=1
FILE_NAME="./files/$1"

delete_lines() {
  if [[ "$LINE_NUMBER" -gt "1" ]]; then
    sed -i "2,${LINE_NUMBER}d" "$FILE_NAME"
  fi
  exit
}

trap delete_lines ERR INT TERM

while IFS="|" read -r rec_column1 rec_column2 rec_column3 rec_column4
do
  cd /posts/ &&
  wp post create \
      --post_type=post \
      --post_title="$rec_column1" \
      --post_status=publish \
      --post_category=2 \
      --url=http://127.0.0.1/ \
      --meta_input="{\"word\":\"$rec_column2\"}" \
      --tags_input="$rec_column3" \
      --post_content="$rec_column4"
  LINE_NUMBER=$((LINE_NUMBER+1))
done < <(tail -n +2 "$FILE_NAME") > ./logs/$1.log

delete_lines
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have limited knowledge with Linux bash script. Will it be possible for you to rewrite my code to include your solution?

Comment: @user3063297 look at my answer,, Your code with his solution

Comment: @user3063297 I have updated my answer, you can try the whole solution code.

Comment: I got a strange error: 
`sed: can't read ./files/ica-changes_1.csv: No such file or directory` but the file is in that location

Comment: @user3063297 The problem might be `cd /posts/` command inside the while loop. Maybe you should `cd` back to the default directory inside `delete_lines()`. `cd -` should be sufficient.

Comment: I have another question, how can I make this so the lines will be deleted as we go and not only on trap. a use case for this is if a hard reset has happened or a power outage

Comment: @user3063297 I think it is not a good idea to read and modify the same file simultaneously. But you could copy the file using `cp`, read from the original and modify the copy. Copied file would have some suffix (e. g. `-1`). After hard reset bash script would run again, automatically detect there is this file with suffix and use it as data source instead of the original file, which could be removed by this moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
trap delete_lines EXIT ERR INT TERM

delete_lines() {
  sed -i "2,${LINE_NUMBER}d" ${FILES_DIR}/$FILE_NAME
  exit
}

FILE_NAME="$1"
FILES_DIR="/path/to/files"
LOGS_DIR="/path/to/logs"

while IFS="|" read -r LINE_NUMBER rec_column1 rec_column2 rec_column3 rec_column4
do
cd /posts/ &&
wp post create \
    --post_type=post \
    --post_title="$rec_column1" \
    --post_status=publish \
    --post_category=2 \
    --url=http://127.0.0.1/ \
    --meta_input="{\"word\":\"$rec_column2\"}" \
    --tags_input="$rec_column3" \
    --post_content="$rec_column4"
done < <(awk 'NR!=1 { print NR"|"$0}' ${FILES_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}) > ${LOGS_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}.log
```

delete_lines

Comment: I got a strange error: 
`sed: can't read ./files/ica-changes_1.csv: No such file or directory`
but the file is in that location

Comment: @user3063297 it's because you change the directory at `cd posts`. use `FILES_DIR="/path/to/files"  and LOGS_DIR="/path/to/logs"`..

Comment: tried this got this error: `sv.log: No such file or directory`
and sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'